# Python3 download remote gzip file to csv reader in memory

Tags: csv, gzip, python-3.6

I'm trying to migrate a project to python3. I'm downloading a gzip file, reading in memory and parsing as a csv reader object.
When it comes to looping through the reader, i'm only getting the first character instead of the whole row. Where am i going wrong?

```
response = requests.get(feed_url, stream=True)
f = io.BytesIO(response.content)
fh = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=f)
reader = csv.reader(fh.read().decode('utf-8'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
for row in reader:
    print(row)
    break
```